# Strip one level of braces for using keyval-value within nested keyval

Tags: braces, xkeyval

I have defined my own figure command using xkeyval and I want to pass arguments for the nested \includegraphics as one of its keyvalues (maybe I stripped too much code, but I hope you get the idea):

```
\makeatletter
  \define@key[foo]{bar}{options}{\def\FooBarOptions{#1}}
  \define@key[foo]{bar}{label}{\def\FooBarLabel{#1}}
  \define@key[foo]{bar}{caption}{\def\FooBarCaption{#1}}
\makeatother

%\MySpecialFigure[keyvals]{filename}
\newcommand{\MySpecialFigure}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \setkeys[foo]{bar}{options={}, label={}, caption={}}
    \setkeys[foo]{bar}{#1}

    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[\FooBarOptions]{#2}
      \caption{\FooBarCaption}
      \label{\FooBarLabel}
    \end{figure}
  \endgroup
}
```

I want to use it like:

```
\MySpecialFigure[options={width=0.5\textwidth, draft}, 
                 label={fig:label},
                 caption={My Caption}]
{my-pic.png}
```

Because of the braces around the options, the whole block gets parsed as one value at `\includegraphics` and behaves like:

```
\includegraphics[{width=0.5\textwidth, draft}]{my-pic.png}
```

I get error:

`Package xkeyval Error:'width=0.5\textwidth, draft' undefined in families 'Gin'`

I tried

```
  \define@key[foo]{bar}{options}{\edef\FooBarOptions{#1}}
```

but that wouldn' strip the braces either.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to expand the `\FooBarOptions` before you feed it to `\includegraphics`, otherwise it is taken as one key. This has nothing to do with an extra layer of braces.

Turning

```
\includegraphics[\FooBarOptions]{#2}
```

into

```
\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\FooBarOptions]{#2}
```

should fix it.

Comment: It works like that. Why do I need expandafter twice? I tried both `\expandafter\includegraphics[\FooBarOptions]{#2}` and `\includegraphics\expandafter[\FooBarOptions]{#2}`

Comment: @B3ret: An `\expandafter` "jumps" over the next token (e.g. macro), so the first one jumps over `\includegraphics` and would expand `[` if the second one is not there. This one then jumps over the `[` and expands `\FooBarOptions`. One way to avoid this is to define the `[ ]` as part of `\FooBarOptions`: `\def\FooBarOptions{[#1]}`. Then you can use `\expandafter\includegraphics\FooBarOptions{#2}`. However, `\includegraphics\expandafter[\FooBarOptions]{#2}` would make `\includegrpahics be expanded first and then take `\expandafter` as first mandatory argument, which causes of course trouble.