# Nested keyval proper parsing

Tags: arguments, xkeyval

I have two families of keyval arguments, and two functions, and I want them to behave like on toy MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\define@key{A}{a1}{\def\a@aOne{#1}}
\define@key{A}{a2}{\def\a@aTwo{#1}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\A}{ m }{%
    \begingroup
        \setkeys{A}{a1={}, a2={}, #1}
        \fbox{$a_1$ = \a@aOne, $a_2$ = \a@aTwo}
    \endgroup
}

\define@key{B}{left}{\def\b@left{#1}}
\define@key{B}{right}{\def\b@right{#1}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\B}{ m }{%
    \begingroup
        \setkeys{B}{left={}, right={}, #1}
        \A{\b@left} \A{\b@right}
    \endgroup
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

    \A{a1=1, a2=2}

    \B{left={a1=1, a2=2}, right={a1=1, a2=2}}

\end{document}
```

However I get an error that `! Package xkeyval Error: 'a1=1, a2=2' undefined in families 'A' at line with using command`B`.

After reading [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15808/strip-one-level-of-braces-for-using-keyval-value-within-nested-keyval) I understood why it happens, but could not apply given suggestions in my case. How to make proper parsing in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this case the solution is simply to expand the `\b@...` keys using `\expandafter` such that their expanded values are passed to `\A`. So change your `\B` definition to the following:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\B}{ m }{%
    \begingroup
        \setkeys{B}{left={}, right={}, #1}%
        \expandafter\A\expandafter{\b@left}%
        \expandafter\A\expandafter{\b@right}%
    \endgroup
}
```

---

Full updated example (with some extra `%`s added at the end of lines to prevent extra spaces in the output):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\define@key{A}{a1}{\def\a@aOne{#1}}
\define@key{A}{a2}{\def\a@aTwo{#1}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\A}{ m }{%
    \begingroup
        \setkeys{A}{a1={}, a2={}, #1}%
        \fbox{$a_1$ = \a@aOne, $a_2$ = \a@aTwo}%
    \endgroup
}

\define@key{B}{left}{\def\b@left{#1}}
\define@key{B}{right}{\def\b@right{#1}}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\B}{ m }{%
    \begingroup
        \setkeys{B}{left={}, right={}, #1}%
        \expandafter\A\expandafter{\b@left}%
        \expandafter\A\expandafter{\b@right}%
    \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \A{a1=1, a2=2}

    \B{left={a1=1, a2=2}, right={a1=3, a2=4}}

\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I would go with `l3keys` directly:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\evalA}{m}
 {
  \robur_eval_a:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\evalB}{m}
 {
  \robur_eval_b:n { #1 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { robur/A }
 {
  a1 .tl_set:N = \l__robur_A_aone_tl,
  a2 .tl_set:N = \l__robur_A_atwo_tl,
 }
\keys_define:nn { robur/B }
 {
  left .tl_set:N = \l__robur_B_left_tl,
  right .tl_set:N = \l__robur_B_right_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \robur_eval_a:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { robur/A } { a1=, a2=, #1 }
  \fbox{$a\sb{1}=\l__robur_A_aone_tl$,~$a\sb{2}=\l__robur_A_atwo_tl$}
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \robur_eval_a:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \robur_eval_b:n
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { robur/B } { left=, right=, #1 }
  \robur_eval_a:V \l__robur_B_left_tl
  \robur_eval_a:V \l__robur_B_right_tl
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\evalA{a1=1, a2=2}

\evalB{left={a1=1, a2=2}, right={a1=3, a2=4}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

No `\expandafter`, thanks to the `V` variant: `\robur_eval_a:V <tl variable>` is the same as

```latex
\robur_eval_a:n { <contents of the tl variable> }
```